# How to link out to a YouTube Playlist in the official app from my own mobile app

Tags: ionic-framework, youtube

I am working on an ionic application. I've successfully been able to use my app to open the official youtube application to play a single video using the following:

`youtube://kVHB26MAh2E`

However, I would like to open a playlist page in the official app, so I tried this:

`youtube://playlist?list={my playlist ID}`

but that did not work. The syntax is a little different for these "deeplinks" so what exactly am I missing?

Thank you very much!

If it helps, this is how I manage fallback urls. I trigger the initial call with `openYouTube()`:

```
  launchExternalApp(iosSchemaName: string, androidPackageName: string, appUrl: string, httpUrl: string, id: string) {
    let app: string;
    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      app = androidPackageName;
    } else if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      app = iosSchemaName;
    } else {
      this.iab.create(httpUrl + id);
      return;
    }

    this.appAvailability.check(app).then(
      () => { // success callback
        this.iab.create(appUrl + id);
      },
      () => { // error callback
        this.iab.create(httpUrl + id);
      }
    );
  }

  openYouTube() {
    this.launchExternalApp('youtube://', 'com.youtube.android', 'youtube://playlist?list=', 'https://youtube.com/playlist?list=', 'PLTzXf6BfROEktE823y4AuhQrvJP2ZuX6q');
  }
```

Comment: Not sure if this might help: *Only videos can be shared on YouTube’s mobile site. Additional features for playlists on m.youtube.com will be coming soon.* - [source](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/57793?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en).

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to do it:

`youtube://youtube.com/playlist?list={id}`

This at least works for iOS, I have not tested android yet.